# How to vectorize a function with multiple if statements?

Tags: r, function, vectorization

I have a function to clean state names using a lookup table

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
lkt <- data_frame(state=state.abb, state_name=state.name)
cleanState <- function(x, lkt) {
  x <- stringr::str_trim(x)
  if(any(str_detect(x, fixed(lkt$state_name, ignore_case = T)))) {
    grep(x, lkt$state_name, useBytes = T, value=T, ignore.case = T)

    } else if (any(str_detect(x, fixed(lkt$state, ignore_case = T)))) {
      grep(x, lkt$state, useBytes = T, value=T, ignore.case = T)
    } else {
      NA
    }
}
```

However I would like to vectorize it to run it on a vector of state names or abbreviations such as `x <- c('MN', 'Texas', 'Neww York')`, which should retrieve a vector `('Minnesota', 'Texas', NA)`.

I've tried with nested `ifelse` but still I can't get it to work, and I know I could use `sapply` but I would rather vectorize this function, so that I can pass a vector to `x`.

Comment: It is a bit hard to help you when your code does not run. The `lkt` object is not defined. The `data_frame` function does not exist. You also have a `y`-argument in the definition of `cleanState`.

Comment: `x <- c('MN', 'Texas', 'Neww York');lookup <- c("MN"="Minnesota", "Texas"="Texas");lookup[x]` maybe?

Comment: @AEBilgrau Sorry for that, I edited the code.

Comment: you can use `unlist(x, use.names = FALSE)` at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way of doing it if I correctly understand what you want:

```
lkt <- data.frame(state=state.abb, state_name=state.name,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
cleanState2 <- function(x) {
  get.ind <- function(s) {
    out <- grep(s, paste(lkt$state_name, lkt$state, sep = "|"), ignore.case = TRUE)
    ifelse(identical(out, integer(0)), NA, out)
  }
  ind <- unlist(sapply(x, get.ind))
  lkt$state_name[ind]
}

x <- c('MN', 'Texas', 'Neww York')
cleanState2(x)
#[1] "Minnesota" "Texas"     NA
```